# rpivottable shiny date descending order

Tags: date, shiny, rpivottable

How can I sort my rows which are in yyyy-mm-dd format to be descending in rpivottable output in Shiny r?

I expect rows to be most recent to older dates. I know for example how to sort by month using the below code in the sorter part, but not in date format.

```
sorters="
    function(attr) {
        var sortAs = $.pivotUtilities.sortAs;
        if (attr == \"ContractCalendarMonth\") 
        { 
            return sortAs([\"7\", \"8\", \"9\", \"10\", \"11\", \"12\", \"1\", \"2\", \"3\",\"4\", \"5\", \"6\"]);
        }
    }"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse the date so that the most recent dates are in the first rows of the rpivotTable is to put the below code into the sorters option of the rpivotTable.

```
sorters = "function(attr) {
    var sortAs = $.pivotUtilities.sortAs;
    if (attr == \"Date\") 
        { return sortAs;  }
}"
```